# Flexibly scanning multiple tables with concise results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**EDIT: I figured out a significant issue with my code - I had set @IDno as an integer, which was not comparable with @FirstScan or @SecondScan. Setting that to an NVarchar made it work!**

Stupid intern learning SQL here. Most of my programming experience is with Python, so this is... very different to me. Basically, we have a database that has ~30 different tables with ~11k rows and ~40 columns each. Some rows (name, address, phone number) should always be displayed, and the user will select two others: they will select an identifying number (as each table has the ID# once, it will display one row from each table) and a column they wish to view (e.g. Employees, Assets, etc.)

Here's the code that I have right now, which is maybe halfway to full functionality (and definitely riddled with bad practices.) I've changed some of the variable names to be more generic so I won't reveal too much about the company - it shouldn't be relevant anyway. The code to take the ID# is broken, but aside from that, it does technically take the relevant data (including the desired column from @Column), compare the ID#s to only show those, and then put them in one output.

```
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(25)
       ,@FirstScan NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@SecondScan NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@IDno INT
SET @Column = '"5F(2)(f)"'
SET @IDno = 19616
SET @FirstScan = N'SELECT [Organization ID#] AS ID#, 
    Registered#, 
    [Legal Name],
    '+@Column+',
    [Latest Form Filing Date]
       FROM dbo.[FORM_2015-09] 
       WHERE 
        [Organization ID#] = '+@IDno''

SET @SecondScan = N'SELECT [Organization ID#] AS ID#, 
    Registered#, 
    [Legal Name],
    '+@Column+',
    [Latest Form Filing Date]
    FROM dbo.[FORM_2015-08] 
    WHERE 
        [Organization CRD#] = '+@IDno'

EXECUTE(@FirstScan+ ' UNION ALL ' + @SecondScan)
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this cobbled-together code's the best I've got. If anyone has a better method of solving this problem (instead of just dissecting the code and what's bad about it,) PLEASE suggest something. I'm willing to toss all this out and rewrite if it means accomplishing the task in a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables all have the same columns you should start by doing yourself a favor and creating a view:

```
create view v_forms as 
    select * from [FORM_2015-09]  union all
    select * from [FORM_2015-08]  union all
    . . .;
```

Then something like your dynamic SQL on the view should be easier to write.

Note:  splitting data into multiple different tables with the same columns is bad practice.  SQL works very well on large tables and there is no reason to keep a multitude of similar smaller tables around.

Comment: Not all of the columns are about the same - the tables are monthly results of forms, and the form changes a little bit every year or so. I'll try this out on the ones for the past several months, though.

Comment: However, having on average made the switch, views have made this much easier. Thanks!